# Why is my setState in function call after popping out of screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

So I'm trying to setState of my widget when popping out of another navigator screen and for some reason it just won't work.

Here's my code..

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  void set() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
            child: IconButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    iconSize: 30,
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications_active_outlined),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (_) => const NextScreen()))
                          .then((value) {
                        set;
                      });
                    }),
        ],
      ),),
}
```

The set state works if I put it directly in as`.then((value) { setState(() {});});` but I need a function as I'm planning on setting the states from some other screens as well and passing a function would be the best way to do so.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

you are calling your set function incorrectly

should be

```
set()
```